# Import error for gym in ros melodic python2.7

Tags: python, ros, openai-gym

I installed gym using `sudo pip install gym`. But when I try to import in python2.7 for my ros project, it throws import error.
When I try to rerun pip install it says

```
The directory '/home/monojit/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/monojit/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: gym in /home/monojit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /home/monojit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in /home/monojit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from gym)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet<=1.5.0,>=1.4.0 in /home/monojit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle~=1.2.0 in /home/monojit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34~=1.1.6 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from gym)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /home/monojit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyglet<=1.5.0,>=1.4.0->gym)
```

I also ran `pip list` to see if gym was installed, but it is not installed.

How do I solve this? I also tried to install from repository, but it requires python3.5+.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run "pip list" or "sudo pip list". Since you installed it using sudo, if you just run pip list you won't see it there. I suggest just to uninstall it then reinstall like this:

```
sudo pip uninstall gym
pip install gym
```